# CPP lint: Can you enforce use of this for class variables?

Tags: c++, cpplint

Is there a lint script that will enforce use of this for class variables?

Ex -

```
class A {
    int var1;

    void func() {
        return var1;
    }
}
```

should be -

```
class A {
    int var1;

    void func() {
        return this->var1;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"should be"* - Is this a coding style requirement or some misguided assumption?

Comment: basically there should be clear distinction between class and local variables. One way to do that is to name class variables with some rule(like adding an underscore). But if you can enforce this, that shouldn't be required

Comment: You don't think lugging `this->` around is kind of a "naming rule"?

Comment: Ofcourse it is. But I find that more clear than naming variables correctly.

Comment: Having to type an extra 6 characters just to access a member variable sounds like a frustrating rule

Comment: Anyway, do you think it's unnecessary or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Lint only provides rules for suggestions to *improve* your code.