# Is there a way to enforce using "this->" for class members/methods in clang-format/clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, clang-format, clang-tidy

I was searching everywhere, but I probably used the wrong terms. I haven't found an option for this.

The only thing I found is this unanswered question (which is however a bit broader): [CPP lint: Can you enforce use of this for class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186162/cpp-lint-can-you-enforce-use-of-this-for-class-variables) .

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Always good to use approach like mentioned the link you have shared. One way I differentiate member variable vs local variable is Eg: 'm_sum' for member variable and just 'sum' for local variable. If you are trying to enforce this to overcome some code analyser tool notifications, you could probably make it a false positive. Not a suggested practice to use 'this->' in front of all member variables.

Comment: I upvoted this because this is a clear question which shows effort, but I really struggle to agree with the idea ...

Comment: Code formatting is ultimately a topic of personal preference. There are ways to format that gather a certain consensus, but this is about how to do a specific formatting, not if it's good or bad. I also believe consistent formatting is better than """better""" but inconsistent one.

Comment: I'm working on a project where this is one of the requirements in the code style. No reason to discuss. It just has to be that way.

Comment: I wish it had that ability, but the opposite -- enforce disallowing using "this->".

Comment: I created LLVM bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41824 for this issue.

Comment: There's https://oleksandrkvl.github.io/2020/10/16/enforce-this-style-check.html

Comment: @user541686 thanks! The LLVM bug was [moved to github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41169), and I've posted info about this implementation to the bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the [existing options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), I dont believe this is possible with clang-format, not that it will be in the future. 
The main reason for this is the way the program works. It doesn't parse the C++ code into and AST, instead it tokenizes the text without the need for includes (defining what it a member and what is a global variable) not a compile database (influencing defines, include paths ...) It's even possible to give it a piece of code and reformat that.

From the nature of the problem, one could expect, If it can exist within the clang-tooling, to be a compiler warning or clang-tidy. As this should be cheap to check at compile time, a warning could be possible, although, warnings are usually about globally accepted improvements. I don't believe there a consensus on that.

So, that leaves clang-tidy. Looking at [the options](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html), I don't see the option. I see it being possible as a `readability-*` check, as more controversial checks are allowed in here. Though, I think if you want this, you should write it yourself and provide it to the project.

A final personal note: I am not convinced that `this->` is a good solution, though nor is starting everything with `m_` (already possible), or not doing it.  It would be nice if the check would be configurable to add/remove `this->`, so one could try things out.

Answer (score 4):

From the look of clang-format's documentation on its style [options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), this doesn't seem possible.